# IE 8 Registry settings for Compatibility View Settings

Tags: internet-explorer-8, registry, settings, compatibility

I need to change the two settings on Compatibility View Settings in IE8 through a script I can send to 1800+ machines.[Compatibility View Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kktf.png)

"Include Updated Websites lists for Microsoft"

and

"Display Intranet sites in Compatibility Mode"

What registry settings do I need to use to change set those settings to off or unchecked on a machine?

Comment: can you show us what you've tried

Comment: I have not tried much because there is very little information out there on this, as far as I can find.  One place said look at 

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

and that entry does not exist on our machines.